# cocos2d and iAd implementations

Tags: iad

I have been trying for weeks to get [Apple's iAd](http://advertising.apple.com/) to work in this cocos2d project but I can't find a resource online that works.

Here is how my project is currently set up.

[image: This is what my project looks like]

Answer (score 0):

In principle and from a configuration standpoint, you only need to include the iAd framework. Go to your project in Xcode, and in "Targets", select your target, "Build Settings" and "Link Binary with Libraries". There, you click the "+" button and look for iAd.framework.

Once this is done, you need to properly use the [iAd Framework Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Reference/iAd_ReferenceCollection/index.html), where you create an object that is the delegate of a banner view object. I recently posted a detailed explanation for doing this (in the context of a Cocos2d-x project) in my [blog](http://becomingindiedev.blogspot.com.es/2015/02/integrating-iad-in-cocos2d-x-v3x.html).